# Code corruption issue between function call and first line of function in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, fltk

I am using visual studio to compile and run a card game. My issue seems to be when I call a function get_top_card()

```
void Deck::shuffle(){
    //This function shuffles the deck.
    Deck tempdeck;                                      
    while (cards.size() > 0)                            
    {
        int cardnumber = -1;                            
        cardnumber = rand() % cards.size();             
        tempdeck.add_card_to_deck(cards[cardnumber],false); 
        erase_card(cardnumber);                         
    }
    while (tempdeck.size() >0){                         
        add_card_to_deck(tempdeck.get_top_card(),false);   //error occurs in this function
    }
}


void Deck::add_card_to_deck(Card& card1, bool shift){       //Lets call this line A
    if (face_up) card1.set_face_up();                       //Lets call this line B
    else card1.set_face_down();
    Point new_location(decklocation.x , decklocation.y + cards.size() * 25);
    if (shift) card1.move_card(card1.location(), new_location);
    else card1.move_card(card1.location(), decklocation);
    card1.button()->hide();
    cards.push_back(card1);
}
```

When I am running this code using the debugger I can see in the live variables that on line A card1 has a valid card value...
[variable view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhEcj.png)

When I get to line B the card1 is now corrupted..
[corrupted variable view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEr7K.png)

Any Ideas?

```
Card& Deck::get_top_card()          //returns the top card and removes it from the deck
{
    Card top_card = cards[cards.size()-1];      //holds the card
    erase_card(cards.size()-1);                 //deletes it from the deck
    return top_card;                
}
```

I think I found the issue see below...testing now

```
Card& Deck::get_top_card()          //returns the top card and removes it from the deck
{
    Card& top_card = cards[cards.size()-1];     //holds the card
    erase_card(cards.size()-1);                 //deletes it from the deck
    return top_card;                
}
```

That was the issue...I was returning a card and not the pointer.
Thank you all for your help!

Update:
I have changed the code even further now due to issues that were eluded to here

1. I have changed my private cards vector to a vector of Card pointers and I push them into the vector using new.

```
cards.push_back (new Card(suit,name,value,symbol,file));
```

2. This means that my functions are now pointer types:

```
Card* Deck::get_top_card()          //returns the top card and removes it from the deck
{
    Card* top_card = cards[cards.size()-1];     //holds the card
    cards.erase(cards.end()-1);                 //deletes it from the deck
    return top_card;                
}

void Deck::add_card_to_deck(Card* card, bool shift){        //adds a card to the bottom of the deck.
    if (face_up) card->set_face_up();
    else card->set_face_down();
    Point new_location(decklocation.x , decklocation.y + cards.size() * 25);
    if (shift) card->move_card(card->location(), new_location);
    else card->move_card(card->location(), decklocation);
    card->button()->hide();
    cards.push_back(card);
}
```

This seems to have solved the issues that I was having. It also allows for only one copy of each card since the address is what is stored and passed.

Does anyone see anything else I might need to be aware of?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: My crystal ball says `get_top_card()` implementation has a bug in it.

Comment: Your `this` variable is different in both of these screenshots. Looks like you're operating on different `Deck` objects at different points in time.

Comment: So anything that happens between the call to `tempdeck.add_card_to_deck` and `this->add_card_to_deck` is a probable culprit. Happy hunting!

Comment: first screenshot is taken before stepping into the function while on line A. The second screen shot is taken after pressing F11. Is there a way to see what is happening between these 2 lines?

Comment: What's F11 do? Is that single step?

Comment: Can you post the code for your `get_top_card()`?

Comment: F11 is step into.

Comment: On line A `this` is already set to invalid value, or contents of the class is thrashed. So whatever happens next is not important, the app is already in Undefined Behavior world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my get top card function.

```
Card& Deck::get_top_card()          
{
    Card& top_card = cards[cards.size()-1];     //needed to create a reference.
    erase_card(cards.size()-1);                 
    return top_card;                
}
```

Update:
This seems to be a better answer:

```
void Deck::add_card_to_deck(Card* card, bool shift){        //adds a card to the bottom of the deck.
    if (face_up) card->set_face_up();
    else card->set_face_down();
    Point new_location(decklocation.x , decklocation.y + cards.size() * 25);
    if (shift) card->move_card(card->location(), new_location);
    else card->move_card(card->location(), decklocation);
    card->button()->hide();
    cards.push_back(card);
}

Card* Deck::get_top_card()          //returns the top card and removes it from the deck
{
    Card* top_card = cards[cards.size()-1];     //holds the card
    cards.erase(cards.end()-1);                 //deletes it from the deck
    return top_card;                
}
```

Comment: This is still wrong and undefined behavior. It seems to work since `erase_card(cards.size()-1);` doesn't overwrite piece of memory where card was stored.

Comment: Thank you for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

First version:

```cpp
Card& Deck::get_top_card()          //returns the top card and removes it from the deck
{
    Card top_card = cards[cards.size()-1];      //holds the card
    erase_card(cards.size()-1);                 //deletes it from the deck
    return top_card;                
}
```

is invalid since you are returning reference to object `top_card` which scope ends. This one is stored on stack and can be easily override. Also CPU may check if memory is access above stack tip leading to a crash.

This version is illegal too:

```cpp
Card& Deck::get_top_card()          
{
    Card& top_card = cards[cards.size()-1];     //needed to create a reference.
    erase_card(cards.size()-1);                 
    return top_card;                
}
```

since this time you are returning reference to tip of vector which is located on heap and you reduce size of vector. This is undefined behavior.

It works since in this scenario vector buffer is not reallocated just size of vector is reduced by one. As a result reference points to valid piece of memory (this prevents crash), but it is still buffer overflow error.

Most probably proper way of fixing it is doping reference from return type:

```cpp
Card Deck::get_top_card()deck
{
    Card top_card = cards[cards.size()-1];
    erase_card(cards.size()-1);
    return top_card;                
}
```

I doubt your `Card` is a complex type and most probably can be cheaply copied around.

Comment: The problem I have with copying it is that each card has multiple images and other graphics attributes which do not behave well when being copied. This is why I was trying to change the behavior in the first place.